# i686-linux-gcc:error trying to exec 'cc1':execvp:No such file or directory

Tags: gcc, linux-kernel, android-source

When I run `make otapackge` on android4.4 ，it runs with the error`i686-linux-gcc:error trying to exec 'cc1':execvp:No such file or directory`when build fs_config,I am very confused about that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it by export PATH=../prebuilts/gcc/linux-x86/host/.../i686-linux/4.4.3/:$PATH